# Drupal five star module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a restaurant site where I display dish pages; customers can rate every dish in my restaurant.

I use Drupal 7,[Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) and [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi). I can rate every dish, but what I want is a window where a customer who gave the maximum vote to a dish can write a "thank you" message to the chef.

Can I do it with Fivestar? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: To which Drupal version are you interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 6, Fivestar comes with "Fivestar Comments" that displays a rating widget when a user posts a comment; the rating of the comment will affect its parent content.

This is the best you can do with the Fivestar module, and without to write any custom code.